# Python3 - how to correctly do absolute imports and make Pylint happy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-import, pylint

I am having a huge trouble trying to understand Python 3 imports (I'm using Python 3.5). This seems to be a million-dollar question and I know it has been answered everywhere. However I don't manage to really get a good understanding of how things are supposed to be done; answers on the Internet vary a lot. So sorry in advance if this is a nearly duplicate answer. I would really appreciate references to good reading material.

So I have the following dummy project:

```
/my_project/main.py
/my_project/lib/__init__.py
/my project/lib/my_lib.py
```

If possible, I would like to:

- Be able to run my program as `python3 main.py`, having `my_project` as current working directory.
- Not modify the `PYTHONPATH` at any time.
- Make pylint happy.
- Use correct Python3 imports.

`main.py` contains:

```
from .lib.my_lib import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

And `foo` is accordingly defined in `lib/my_lib.py`

With that configuration, I get:

`SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

I can get around the error by importing like:

```
from lib.my_lib import foo
```

But then 1) this is not a Python3 absolute import, right? 2) Pylint complains: `Unable to import 'lib.my_lib' (import-error)`

The next thing I tried is to add a `my_project/__init__.py`, and import like this:

```
from my_project.lib.my_lib import foo
```

In this case pylint is happy but then I cannot run as: `python3 main.py`:
`ImportError: No module named 'my_project'`

Then the only way I can run it is from the parent directory as a module: `python3 -m my_project.main`.

So my question is: is it possible at all to do the imports in a correct way, while still being able to execute it as `python3 main.py`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `from lib.my_lib import foo` *is* an absolute import: the current working directory is automatically in `sys.path`, as the first directory even.

Comment: To be more precise (and correct): the first entry in `sys.path` is ["is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with pylint: I don't get an import-error.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that I am running pylint on multiple files in one call, corresponding to other projects. So I have other `my_project2` at the same level as `my_project`. Could it be that it's messing up the path and that's why I get errors importing? I'm not really sure if I'm supposed to run pylint like that, or in a loop, file by file.

Comment: Please update your question with the command you use for running pylint. But it sounds like you want to run pylint once per project. Have you tried that?

Comment: Looks like I'm having trouble to isolate the problem and create a reproducible example out of our repository (which contains many other things). Should I delete the question until I can find a better description? I believe I should start asking how to use Pylint with multiple files; it's not written in the documentation and I find controversial answers on the internet

Comment: I've put in a close vote, which may be the better option. If you figure out how to properly reproduce the problem, that vote can be retracted or the question be reopened with the edit. Unless figuring that out makes the problem go away, then you may want to delete the question (from your last comment, that may become the case).

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
/path/README
/path/requirements.txt
/path/cleverappname/__main__.py
/path/cleverappname/__init__.py
/path/cleverappname/foo.py
/path/cleverappname/bar.py
```

Assuming you have something like `class CleverName(object)` in `__init__.py` and things like `class Foo(object)` in `foo.py` (same for bar, you got the idea).

In `__main__`:

```
from cleverappname import CleverName
from cleverappname.foo import Foo
from cleverappname.bar import Bar
```

But, it needs you to use it as a python and not a script (which is right, because that's what it is): `python3 -m clevername`

Pylint seems happy about that.

Comment: I'd use relative imports for intra-package imports. Just in case one decides to rename the package (or whoever installs it decides to rename it).